# How to cycle through recently *used* tabs in Safari?

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, firefox, tabs

I want to cycle through recently ***used*** tabs in Safari 7.1.3 (MacOS 10.9.5) like one can in in [Firefox](https://superuser.com/a/392376), [Chrome](https://superuser.com/a/433532), and [Opera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqFDf.png). I predominantly run Opera 11.64, and it exhibits the best behavior for this recently-used-tab switching. Is there a way to do this in Safari, even if it requires an extension/plugin/addon of some kind?

Note: cycling/switching between tabs in most-recently-used (aka "visited") order is different than simply cycling through all the tabs as they are listed at the top of the browser; the latter seems more-commonly discussed.

Comment: Interested in getting an answer to this one as well. Should be a must have for every browser!

Comment: related question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/276853/safari-switch-to-last-active-tab?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

From the tips on SnazzyLabs, ⇧-⌘-T  reopens last tab closed (N number of times) AND will restore the last session if all/Safari are closed.

In essence, it is going backwards through your recent history one step at a time.

Comment: SnazzyLabs? Link? I think you misunderstood the question 

Comment: Sorry Thomas, I forgot to provide more info for you,  Snazzy Labs is a production of Nelson Quinn, https://snazzylabs.com/.  I got a lot of hints from his videos on youtube over the lass few years and just copy/pasted them in a file. To find them you would have yo watch a lot of videos here: https://www.youtube.com/c/snazzy/videos.

Comment: Zombie comment here but this is not what the OP asked at all, right? He doesn't want to re-open closed tabs, he wants to switch to the LRU tab. Like the "CLUT: Cycle Last Used Tabs" Chrome extension.

Answer (score 1):

I found these two from the store:

- [Last Tab for Safari](https://www.producthunt.com/products/last-tab-for-safari)
- [Hare - Spotlight for safari](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/hare-spotlight-for-safari/id1538324606?mt=12)