# Toggle between two most recent tabs in Safari

Tags: macos, mac, safari

Chrome was my favorite browser for years, but it drastically overheats MacBook, thus my patience was finally exhausted and I decided to move to Safari as it's the most energy efficient browser for Mac.

The only thing I can't implement here is toggling between two recent tabs using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> or any other custom shortcut. Notice that these tabs shouldn't be necessarily neighboring.

I googled a lot but still can't find extension or property which can help me to accomplish this. I'd be very thankful if you could give me a hint how I can implement this tab toggling

Comment: What versions of macOS and Safari are you running?

Comment: @Monomeeth MacOS Sierra (10.12.3) and Safari v.10.0.3 (12602.4.8)

Comment: It doesn't seem to have one - https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21483

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174949/how-to-cycle-through-recently-used-tabs-in-safari