# Safari Switch to Last Active Tab

Tags: safari, google-chrome, safari-extensions, tabs

OS: Sierra

Safari: 10.0.3

It looks like the functionality to switch to the last active tab is not supported natively. Are there any extensions that can be used for this purpose? Furthermore, is there an extension that would give me a tab manager?

Note that I am unable to switch to a tab through the keyboard using the "Show all tabs" natively. The only solution that I found is through the use of [Shortcat app](https://shortcatapp.com).

I had to switch to using Opera for the time being for its awesome tab manager. With the addition of Vimium I can completely rely on the keyboard for all navigation (only partially supported with Safari through Vimari).

My only issue with Opera is that it isn't integrated with the default autocorrect/spellcheck engine, making life difficult for me.

Any suggestions for a tab manager/last active tab switch in Safari and/or a way to integrate Opera with the autocorrect engine is welcome (the latter, I think is dependent on [this Chromium issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=90278)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that [sVim](https://github.com/flipxfx/sVim) supports this with `"g l"` which maps to `lastActiveTab`.

It doesn't play well with gleeBox, however, so I mapped gleeBox to be launched with the `insert mode`.

Comment: svim is no longer supported

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use Safari as much as I would like. If you have a recommendation please let us know @abbood

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [Recent Tab List](http://nickvdp.com/tablist/)? It's a Safari extension that allows you to manage *open tabs* and *recently closed tabs* in Safari.

You can reopen closed tabs quickly, as well as switch to open tabs. It also provides search functionality, so you can search for a tab. This is particularly useful if you have many tabs open across multiple windows.

**Note:** I am in no way affiliated with this extension.

Comment: Yeah, have come across this one. However does not have MRU tab list, making it difficult to switch to the last active tab.

Answer (score 0):

I found these two from the store:

- [Last Tab for Safari](https://www.producthunt.com/products/last-tab-for-safari)
- [Hare - Spotlight for safari](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/hare-spotlight-for-safari/id1538324606?mt=12)

Comment: Hello, Thomas. This is considered a "link-only" answer. It would be helpful for future visitors to this question if you would [edit] in a summary of that page. Links can become broken or outdated so a summary would still provide the necessary information.

Comment: Hey Agarza, those are the names of the apps, should also work out if links are broken 